# Chrome Setting Overrides not working on mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

I have wrote simple search extension. It works fine on Windows but does not work very well on Mac. Extension sets newTab page, home page and default search provider. But on Mac search provider is not changed (I mean when I type in url field, omnibox), it is still google.

Here is the manifest:

```
{
"name" : "Example",
"short_name" : "example",
"manifest_version" : 2,
"version" : "2.6.1.0",
"description" : "Example Extension Description",

"chrome_settings_overrides" : {
    "homepage" : "http://example.com/",

    "search_provider" : {
        "name": "Example Search Name",
        "is_default" : true,
        "encoding" : "UTF-8",
        "favicon_url": "http://example.com/favicon.png",
        "keyword" : "keyword.example.com",
        "search_url" : "http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&gid=SDD316",
        "suggest_url" : "http://example.com/suggest.php?q={searchTerms}&gid=SDD316"
    },
    "startup_pages" : ["http://example.com"]
},
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab" : "html/newTab.html"
},
"icons" : {
    "128" : "icon128.png",
    "16" : "icon16.png",
    "48" : "icon48.png"
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "w.png",
    "default_title": "Example Search",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
},
"background" : {
    "scripts" : ["js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js", "js/background.js"]
},
"permissions" : ["storage", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "unlimitedStorage", "chrome://favicon/*", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking" ,"cookies", "*://*.test.com/*"],
"content_scripts":  [
    {
        "js": [
            "js/start.js"
        ],
        "matches": [
            "http://example.com/*"
        ],
        "all_frames": false,
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
```

}

Wouldn't `chrome_settings_overrides.search_provider` change search in omnibox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override):

> The API is available only on Windows.

Comment: Ooh, Looks like I missed that line. Is there any way to override omnibox search and set my search to be default?

Comment: I don't think there is, I'm afraid. But I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Settings Overrides is currently available in Windows and Mac, Mac in Chrome 56 and later. No Linux as of yet.

Chrome might be the only browser currently allowing Settings Overrides at some level.

**Trivia**: However general settings overriding (customization (for the user itself own client)) requires more serious security tuning and pruning by core Chromium.

**General about browsers**: Currently browsers are on fast dev cycle - Mozilla/Firefox coming along with Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi and Safari has really spiced up browser dev.

**Settings Overrides soon then?** I'm afraid that's a no. There's so many things happening atm.